# What is this city name in this passenger list from Russia/Poland in late 19th/early 20th century?

Tags: poland, russia, manifest, place-names

The full passenger list can be found below -- I'm looking at the entry for "Stanislaw Walczykowski" line 20.

What is the name of the city he identified as last place of residence and birth place? It was classified then as Russia or Poland.

[image: Last Residence column]
[image: Place of Birth column]

[image]

Comment: Welcome to G&FH SE!  As a new user I hope you will take our 2-minute [Tour] to learn about the site and how it works.  You said "The full passenger list can be found below " but it is not present.  There is an [edit] button beneath your question that you can use to update your question with a picture of or link to that.

Comment: Add the link here as a comment and I'll edit it into your question.  Another workaround would be to combine your two pictures into a single image using something like Paint.NET and then you just use one link for two images.

Comment: Thank you! Here is the full manifest: [link](http://i.stack.imgur.com/G6YoD.jpg)

Comment: Have you looked for and found him in any census records which may name his place of birth in writing that is easier to read?

Comment: Yes but unfortunately they only list the country of origin, not city.

Comment: Have you looked for and found a naturalization record?

Comment: The proper spelling was probably Stanisław Wałczykowski. ('Ł' is pronunced like the 'W' in "Washington" in english language)

Comment: @PolyGeo I will look in Naturalization documents to confirm and see if a city is listed there, thank you!

Comment: We must be related because the Stanislaw you were looking at is my great great grandfather. I am violet's grand daughter.

Comment: City is propably Częstochowa.
Surname in left column can be also Walczikowski which propably is misheard Walczykowski

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The first letter looks like a 'C' and is not very different from the C in Chicago on line 7 or in Cleveland on line 11 (both in column of final destination). The second letter puzzled me first but then, although I don't speak polish, I recalled that the combination 'CZ' is not uncommon in polish, so I go for 'z'. Third and fourth letters looks like 'eu' or 'en' followed by a 't' and 'o'. Next could be 's', 'c' and 'h'. The final two letters could be 'a' or 'o' followed by 'n' or maybe a 'w'. That would yield Czentoschow, but after consulting internet I believe it could be Częstochowa. I would not take this conclusion for granted but as a hint to investigate further.

Also, looking at [an old (1902) russian-polish map](http://feefhs.org/maplibrary/russian/re-polan.html) in the lower left corner an inch over `Krakaw` there is a place called `Czenstochowa`.

[image]

Comment: The proper spelling is actually Częstochowa

Comment: @Tom-Brunberg, thank you for your help. Interesting to see the method by which you attempted to go at this, too -- I will use it next time I'm attempting a difficult transcription!

Comment: You are welcome @David! I just recognized that the ships name provides the best comparison for the initial 'C'. BTW, the ship has intersting ties with Titanic.

Answer (score 0):

I believe it is czetowa (sp) Russian Poland.  That is how it was referred by in my grandparents birth certificates and immigration to Ellis Island. Is this my cousin John or my uncle John.  I was looking for info on Stanley as well.